# Read a text file and write to several text file for filtering/extraction

Tags: java, loops, text, io, count

I am looking for a way to filter my text files. I have many folder names that contain many text files, the text file have several no staff and each staff have 10 cluster/group (I showed only 3 here). But each group/cluster may contain several primitive (I showed 1 and 2 here)

this is my text file for adam, page1_d.txt:

```
 # staff No. 0 //no of staff

 *  0  0  1 //no of cluster

 1 1 1 1 1 1 //one primitive here actually p1 in my Array

 *  0  1  1

 1 1 1 1 1 1 

 *  0  2  1

 1 1 1 1 1 1 

 *  0  3  1

 1 1 1 1 1 1

 # staff No. 1

 *  1  0  2

 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 // two primitive here actually p2 and p3 in my Array
 3 3 3 3 3

 *  1  1  2

 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 3 3 3 3 3

 *  1  2  2

 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 3 3 3 3 3

 *  1  3  2

 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 3 3 3 3 3
```

My public Class:

```
public class NewClass {
String [][][][] list = { {{{"adam"}},{{"p1"},{"p2","p3"}},{{"p4","p5","p6"}}} };
// first is name for the folder, second is num of text file, 3rd num of staff, 4th num of primtive
final int namefolder = list.length;
final int page = list[0].length;
```

This is my method for reading text file and write to another text file:

```
public void search (File folder, int name,int numPage){
    BufferedReader in;
    String line=null;
    int staff = list[name][numPage].length; // the length vary for each txt file

    for (int numStaff=0;numStaff<staff;numStaff++){ 
        int primitive = list[name][numPage][numStaff].length; //the length vary for each staff
        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
        String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(folder));
                for (int numPrim=0;numPrim<primitive;numPrim++) {
                while(( line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (!(line.startsWith("#") ||line.startsWith("*") ||line.isEmpty() )) {
                        contents.append(line);
                        contents.append(separator);
                        try {
                            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C://"+list[name][numPage][numStaff][numPrim]+".txt", true));
                            try {
                                output.println(line);
                            }
                            finally {
                                output.close();
                            }
                            for (int i = numPrim+1; i < primitive; i++){ // this is for more than 2 primitive
                                if((line = in.readLine()) != "\n"){ // 2nd or more primitive has no newline
                                    contents.append(line);
                                    contents.append(separator);
                                    try {
                                        PrintWriter output2 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C://"+list[name][numPage][numStaff][i]+".txt", true));

                                        try {
                                            output2.println(line);
                                        }
                                        finally {
                                          output2.close();
                                        } 
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        System.out.println("Error cannot save");
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("Error cannot save");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                       
                }//end of while
            }// end for loop for prim
                in.close();
            }//end of try
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();      
            }
    }// end for loop for staff
}
```

I want my output like this for p1.txt:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

But it shows this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1
(empty)
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
```

and this (p2.txt):

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

and this (p3.txt):

```
(empty)    
(empty)
(empty)
(empty) 
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: "I want to count the printed lines but it counts the loop" - What's the difference? The code you've posted should print the same count!

Comment: Does `contents` print out the correct lines (i.e. all but the skipped ones)?

Comment: @adarshr yes you are right, there is no problem with the count, it was me who confused the exact problem. Although I have counted the printed lines before, in this program I do not know why the counted line is not the same with the output, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your counter counts how many lines were printed, and is OK, if you want to count how many lines are there at all, move it outside of the if block:

```
while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
    if (!(line.startsWith("#") || line.startsWith("*") ||line.isEmpty() )) {
        contents.append(line);
        contents.append(separator);
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some advice:

1. Split long methods into several, smaller ones
2. If that's hard because you use many local variables, move everything into a parser class and make each local variable a field.
3. Each method should do one single thing.

That allows you to write a filter like so:

```
void parse() {
    while( hasMoreLines() ) {
        if( lineMatches() ) {
            processLine();
        }
    }
}

boolean lineMatches() {
    if( line.startsWith( "#" ) ) return false;
    if( line.startsWith( "*" ) ) return false;

    return true;
}
```

You have now two options: You can check for the pattern `1 1 1 1 1 1` in `lineMatches()` or somewhere in `processLine()`.

If you take the latter approach, you can simply `return` before writing any output.